# Vector product using Levi-Civita

Tags: python, math

I made the program which displays the table of permutations (0,1,2) and Levi-Civita symbol. Now I have to make a program which calculates vector product of 2 vectors using what I have below. How can I make it?
[This is the output I have now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNb51.png)

```
from itertools import product

def epsilon(indexes):
    indexes = list(indexes)
    if len(indexes) != len(set(indexes)):
        return 0
    elif indexes == sorted(indexes):
        return 1
    else:
        for i in range(len(indexes)):
            for j in range(len(indexes) - 1):
                if indexes[i] > indexes[j + 1]:
                    indexes[j], indexes[j + 1] = indexes[j + 1], indexes[j]
                    return -1 * epsilon(indexes)

def draw_table(all_cases):
    epsilonValues = []
    for case in all_cases:
        epsilonValues.append(epsilon(case))
    print('| i | j | k ||| L-C')
    print('|===========|||======')
    k = '|___|___|___|||___'
    print(k)
    i = 0
    for case in all_cases:
        a, b, c = str(case[0]), str(case[1]), str(case[2])
        print('| ' + a + ' | ' + b + ' | ' + c + ' ||| '+ str(epsilonValues[i]))
        i += 1
        print(k)

draw_table(list(product([0, 1, 2], repeat=3)))
```

Comment: The result is a vector so it should be a list e.g. [2,4,2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
a=[2,3,1]
b=[1,2,3]

c=[0,0,0] # initialize

for k in [0,1,2]:
    for i,j in product([0,1,2],repeat=2):
        c[k]=c[k]+ a[i]*b[j]*epsilon([i,j,k])

print(a,b,c) # c is the cross product of the vectors a and b.
```